# Program to find the last three prime number lesser than 100

Tags: java

I am trying to print last three prime numbers less than 100. If I print less than 10 prime number it is working correctly. But when I try to print less than 100 it is not working correctly. I don't know why. Can you tell me an efficient way to print last three numbers?

```
int[] a = new int[100];
int flag=0,c=0,i=2,j=2;
int n=10;
while(i <= n)
{
    flag=0;
    while(j<=i/2)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        a[c]=i;
        c++;
    }
    i++;
}
for(i=0;i<c;i++)
{
    c--;
    System.out.print(a[c]+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to re-init the variables j and flag.

```
while(i <= n) {
    //...

    if(flag==0) {
        a[c]=i;
        c++;
     }
    i++;
    j = 2;
}
```

You can show the last three prime like this

```
for(i = c-1; i >= c-3; i--) {
    System.out.print(a[c]+" ");
}
```

Or you can use this code

```
int numToShow = 3, n = 100;
boolean isPrime = true;

while(n > 1 && numToShow > 0) {
    for (int j = 2; j <= (int) Math.sqrt(n) && isPrime; j++) {
        if(n % j == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
        }
    }

    if (isPrime) {
        System.out.print(n + " ");
        numToShow--;
    }

    isPrime = true;
    n--;
}
```